# how to add a h1 inside a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a HTML where I want to populate a `h1` using `Javascript`. Here I'm able to populate text, but not the `h1`. Below is my code.

```
function getTheIncident(keyWord, text) {
    showTheDiv();
    console.log(keyWord + "\t" + text);

    var e = document.getElementById('textResult');
    e.innerHTML = text.replace('\^', '\'');
}
```

and this gives me the output as shown in the picture below.

[image]

MY aim is to add a `h1` with content as `Description`. Basically like

```
<h1>Description</h1>
```

just above `A procurement order has been placed for a RAM with 128 Gig`

please let me know on how can I do this.

Comment: show us your html.

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

```
 var h1= document.createElement('H1');
   h1.innerHTML = "Description";
```

now add this element to a particular node you want

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the code to be added as HTML into an `h1`:

```
function getTheIncident(keyWord, text) {
    showTheDiv();
    console.log(keyWord + "\t" + text);

    var e = document.getElementById('textResult');
    e.innerHTML = "<h1>" + text.replace('\^', '\'') + "</h1>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://fiddle.jshell.net/LnkfLrev/1/ Something like this? you can use `document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML = text;` to set the text of you `h1`element

EDIT:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/LnkfLrev/2/

Sorry, I did not quiet get you question. I updated the fiddle so it works as an anwer

I created an H1 element with var `h = document.createElement("H1");`

then i set the Text and add it to the body

```
  h.innerHTML = text;
  document.body.appendChild(h);
```

hope this helps now

Comment: He wants to create a new H1 tag using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Create your tag by using `createElement()`, then `prepend()` it to your container where you want to have on first. Check below snippet for reference.

```js
var h1Tag = document.createElement('H1');
h1Tag.innerHTML = "Your Title";
$('.output').prepend(h1Tag);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="output">
  This div contains the output..
</div>
```

Comment: This question is not about jQuery, so your answer is out of scope here.

Comment: hope there is no word about ***only***  javascript!

Comment: The question is not tagged jquery, so assuming the op uses jquery is premature. In the case he/she is not already using jquery, jquery is a dependency of you answer. Since the problem is solvable without jquery, your answer is not a good idea here.